# Getting unusual traffic on website on (/safeview-redirect/tc_frame.html?)

Tags: security, web, redirect, bots, cloudflare

My website is getting some unusual traffic. I see this in my Google Analytics account.

[Screenshot of Google Analytics Realtime hit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asmdb.png)

And, I am getting ton of these in REAL time.

These link starts with `/safeview-redirect/tc_frame.html?dt=xxxxxxxxxxx…` very long include many thing and parameters.

This is one of the link, which I have copied:

`/safeview-redirect/tc_frame.html?dt=PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+&n=94289b35&furl=YWJvdXQ6c3JjZG9j&turl=aHR0cHM6Ly9nZXR2b2ljZS5vcmcvc2VhcmNoP3E9V2hhdCtpbmZyb21hdGlvbittb3N0K2xpa2VseStwcmVzZW50cythK3NlY3VyaXR5K3Jpc2srb24reW91citwZXJzb25hbA==`

This add with my homepage like `example-domain.com/safeview-redirect/…`

When, I open this link with my domain addded, they all land on 404 page.

Very less information is available on web about this. I have posted this on Cloudflare community (since, I use it for DNS proxy and DDoS mitigation). But, didn't got any answer about this till now. See [here](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/getting-weired-type-of-traffic-safeview-redirect-tc-frame-html-urgent-help/427472).

**My question**:

1. What type of traffic is this?
2. Is this Bot or fake traffic?
3. Is this any sort of Attack?
4. What should I do know to fix this thing?

**For the time being, I have enabled `I am Under Attack mode` in Cloudflare and surprisingly, these aren't coming. But, my visitors are seeing JS question which let to go back and eventually, losing traffic.**

---

**Additional information**:

- CMS used: Question2Answer.org
- Location of Attack coming (as per Google Analytics): Boydton, USA.

Comment: Hello, Kundan. I wonder if you were able to find anything useful about this issue. Do you possible have advertisements or external sources loaded in iframes on your pages?

Comment: @smozgur I use Google Ads for advertising. There isn't anything 'external sources loaded in iframe' as per my knowledge. I have dig into it and found that it might be some sort of Ads quality check for an ad agency but I was getting too many request. So, I have blocked any request to that particular PATH using Cloudflare WAF.